# laravel passport and endpoint permissions

Tags: php, laravel, api, permissions

I am writing an api that is going to hook into a vue.js front end. I have 4 user types that can all do something different, on the front I have logic in place to check the user level and not let them into parts of thh site they are not allowed.

On the API side how do I enforce that they can only do the actions to which they are allowed? Do I use scopes attached to the users token? Or do implement something like Entrust or Laratrust.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a Middleware or [Laravel Gates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization).

I'm not 100% how are you handling the permission in your application but I would use the Gates approach so you can do something like `$user->can('edit', $post)` in your controller. This returns a 403 if the logic of your gates returns false